# how to get filename by file_id in telegram

Tags: file, telegram, telegram-bot

for my new bot i need to get real file name.
when i get the file_id and requesting for generate download link with  "get file" commend, the file name is look like "file_370.mp3" but the real file name is:"michaeljackson.mp3".

i tried this code:

```
 $mp3name = $result['message']['audio']['title'];
   $mp3fileid = $result['message']['audio']['file_id'];

   file_get_contents( $url."/sendaudio?chat_id=118718802&audio=$mp3fileid&performer=awaperformer&title=awatitle");



$bot_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$file_path_gen_url = $bot_url."/getfile?file_id=".$mp3fileid;
// file_get_contents( $url."/sendmessage?chat_id=118718802&text=lastfileid:filegen:$file_path_gen_url");


$file_path_result = file_get_contents($file_path_gen_url);

// echo "last file id: $last_file_id <br>";

$file_path_result = json_decode($file_path_result, TRUE);


$file_path = $file_path_result['result']['file_path'];

// echo "file_path: $file_path <br>";

$file_url = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot".$botToken."/".$file_path;
```

how can i get real file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get original file name for audio object.

here avaliable attributes : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#audio

You can get original file name for document object.

Comment: thank u for your answer Danil. when we want download mp3 file in telegram like normal member file name is real! but when we download it with bot the name is not real! i want trick to do that with bot.